# WPF Xaml MainWindow dissappears after its called using Show function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a barebones WPF project in Microsoft Expression Blend 4.

I then opened the project in Visual Studio 2012, and added a simple Class to the project.

I Set the application properties to use this class as the Startup Object.

I created a new mainwindow, and then used the show function for the object.

The window pops up for a millisecond and then closes.

How do I call the MainWindow so it so it stays open?

**Class1.cs**

```
//This is the Class I created
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    static class Class1
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            MainWindow winMain = new MainWindow();
            winMain.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
//This is the Mainwindow.xaml.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"/>
</Window>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication5.App"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that Class1.cs ? You have already defined entry point of your application in App.xaml by setting StartupUri.

Comment: I wonder you didn't get any exception when compiling the project because of setting 2 entry points. So better remove 
[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            MainWindow winMain = new MainWindow();
            winMain.Show();
        }

Comment: I am using Class1.cs as the simplest example I can, Class1 will eventually contain the core program code, and make calls out to other classes, and I will need to display several windows, depending on what happens in the code. Thus the need/want to call xaml windows through code. I did not receive any exceptions, and so far nobody has answered question. I tried removing the Startupuri call from App.xaml, and that didnt work either.  Thanks!

Comment: You can create and show any number of windows from your code. It is just you do not need that Main method in Class1.cs to specify the entry point of your application again.

Comment: I removed the other entry point from App.xaml, so there is no longer 2 entry points, and calling the mainwindow makes it disappear. So how would I call it, or any other window, and from where? If I had a mainwindow2, how would I call it? Thanks!

Comment: using ShowDialog instead of Show seems to work.

Comment: Check this link. It looks promising in your issue.
http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2010/08/26/136/wpf-where-is-your-static-main-method

Comment: That is good information! Thanks Nitesh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set two entry points for the application. One is in App.xaml and other is in Class1.cs. So better remove below code block from your Class1.cs

```
[STAThread] 
static void Main() 
{
  MainWindow winMain = new MainWindow();
  winMain.Show();
}
```